# Cocoapods 1.1.0 beta for Swift3

Tags: cocoapods, swift3

After upgrading to Xcode8 with Swift3, I found Cocoapods doesn't support this any more. So I upgraded the Cocoapods to beta version, which is 1.1.0rc2. But when I try to pod spec lint, error happened:

```
- ERROR | xcodebuild:  WeatherKit/WeatherKit/DateComponents+InitFromString.swift:11:11: error: use of undeclared type 'DateComponents'
- ERROR | [iOS] xcodebuild:  WeatherKit/WeatherKit/CityLoader.swift:14:13: error: use of undeclared type 'DispatchQueue'
- ERROR | [iOS] xcodebuild:  WeatherKit/WeatherKit/CityLoader.swift:19:11: error: use of unresolved identifier 'DispatchQueue'
- WARN  | [iOS] xcodebuild:  WeatherKit/WeatherKit/DirectionUnit.swift:20:15: warning: extraneous '_' in parameter: 'value' has no keyword argument name
- WARN  | [iOS] xcodebuild:  WeatherKit/WeatherKit/DistanceUnit.swift:19:15: warning: extraneous '_' in parameter: 'value' has no keyword argument name

Analyzed 1 podspec.

[!] The spec did not pass validation, due to 20 errors and 2 warnings.
```

The 20 errors are all about the Swift3 grammar. But I am using Xcode8, which should allow all those grammars

Do anyone know what I can do with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved the problem by using the 1.1.0rc2 version.

The problem is due to the wrong swift compile version, which is by default 2.3, but the code is 3.0.

So change the validator.rb :

```
# @return [String] the SWIFT_VERSION to use for validation.
#
def swift_version
  @swift_version ||= dot_swift_version || '2.3'
end
```

to

```
# @return [String] the SWIFT_VERSION to use for validation.
#
def swift_version
  @swift_version ||= dot_swift_version || '3.0'
end
```

The problem solved

Answer (score 0):

I would try going back to the old version and leaving the podFile as iOS 9 instead of iOS 10. I'm assuming this error is a bug in the beta version of CocoaPods.

Comment: But when I roll back, this shows up "- ERROR | [iOS] unknown: Encountered an unknown error (Simulator iPhone 4s is not available.) during validation."

Comment: I don't think iPhone 4S is an option in the Xcode 8 sim (or it shouldn't be). Try using the iPhone SE.

Comment: But it doesn't work like that with Cocoapods. I have tried to change the simulator to iPhone5, but it still does not work. But it's solved, see my answer above